# Request: Please Reopen This Question

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

Please reopen this question:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662540/any-one-like-me-who-still-believes-in-aspnet-web-forms-or-has-evryone-switched-t

Reasons:

1. Nick Craver (correctly) voted to close this question because it should have been a 'Community Wiki'. Now it *is* a 'Community Wiki' so that should, at a minimum, nullify his vote.
2. *Many* developers are asking the same question; and they're looking for convincing arguments in either direction. That's why this is an extremely worthwhile question and why it's precisely the type of content that makes SO so valuable and useful. Opinions voiced in this discussion might lead a developer to pursue a certain path (i.e. to learn ASP.NET MVC or not learn ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: Community wiki is not a *carte blanche* for asking questions that don't belong on Stack Overflow. The question was closed rightfully and will remain closed.

Comment: Arguments, opinions, and discussion are *not* the type of content that makes SO so valuable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**

As already pointed out in the comments:

- **CW does not mean a question can be subjective**. CW allows the community to collaborate on a post and allows users to edit posts with only 100 rep. It also means the community owns the question. **It is not a method to get subjective question to be allowed**
- It's a discussion and purely up for speculation. It might be allowed on [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) but definitely has not value on SO.