# Are requests to reopen a question appropriate for meta?

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopen-closed

My question was closed as "Not a real question" by a user with more than 3K reputation and a moderator. Therefore I searched on meta for a way to reopen my question and found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120372/make-the-faq-clear-on-how-a-question-can-be-reopened) post which had many up votes so I decided to follow the suggestions. It suggested the user to make some edits and flag the post for moderator review and post a "request" on meta. But I found that some requests were also closed on meta with many down votes like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66318/request-please-reopen-this-question) one. Therefore I am confused now if a request should be posted on meta for reopening a closed question or not but I have already flagged my edited question for moderator review.

Comment: Can you link to your closed question ? I think it's useful here for the discussion to be based on a concrete question.

Comment: For reference, if I'm not mistaken, the closed question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801806/how-to-create-a-single-star-schema-using-ssis-for-two-different-domains) (@dystroy)

Comment: @dystroy - yes that is my question

Comment: I don't think this question should be reopened, at least on SO. It's in this grey area where OP probably can't display more effort and a discussion would be interesting but in which we can hardly give a clear definite answer. A forum, a chat, or *maybe* another SE site, would be more suited.

Comment: @dystroy - Thanks for pointing that out. I will try to post it on some other forum.

Comment: This is a good question to have around, as meta can be a little inconsistent in how this type of question / request is handled. Good on you for taking time to look around to see how well it would be received, not many people take the time to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a closed question is edited for improvement, it enters a [reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) where other users can see what changed. If the question has been sufficiently improved, it will likely be reopened. If not, additional edits are most likely needed.

If your question was *not* reopened within a day or so, and you feel that you *did* sufficiently improve it, you can flag it for a moderator's attention to be reviewed. To do this, select 'other' as the reason and let them know you've made what you feel are the necessary edits. If the moderator agrees with you, they'll reopen your question. If they don't, they'll probably leave some feedback when declining your flag. Make sure to check your flag status page to see this information if that's the case.

If you've done that, and *honestly* feel that your question now meets our topic and quality criteria, and can't understand what else you could possibly do to improve it, then yes - you're more than welcome to come here to meta to ask for help. When you do:

- Let us know that you've made all of the edits that you can,
- Let us know that you addressed any feedback the moderators might have left you directly, reiterate the feedback in your meta post if they left any,
- Be constructive. If you want help, just ask for it - but try not to 'ask angry'.

Questions of this nature on Meta are generally well received *if* effort on your part is apparent, you'll likely see your question edited into shape by others if it can be saved if you post constructively here.

Just ... try to help yourself first :)

Comment: Trivial but worth also mentioning, if you have not yet edited your question, but it has received reopen votes, it will also appear in the queue. In other words, if you feel it can be edited but someone has already voted to reopen, get on that edit as soon as you can to take advantage of the question being in the queue.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I did edit the question. Previously it was very specific to my problem (including the details of my database and what i did to understand the concepts) but i got a reply saying "People wont have time to review......". Therefore i deleted most of the details and asked a basic question on the concept then flagged it to reopen. Since its on a particular concept i am unable to show what i attempted. Its a very basic question for those who know SSIS. Hope it gets reopened because am very new to the concept and some help would be great.

Comment: I think that this answer should be the answer to this question:
_"How to let the mods know about my modified question?"_

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Meta is the correct place to post reopen requests, though we suggest that you make edits to improve it first.

In my opinion, [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801806/how-to-create-a-single-star-schema-using-ssis-for-two-different-domains) should not be reopened *in its present state*. The reasons are:

- You have not shown an attempt to solve the problem
- The question is very unclear
- The question does not address a specific problem

You are more than welcome to edit your question to make it more applicable and specific, at which point, we will be more than happy to reopen it.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. The link i provided is not my question of concern. I just wanted to know if posting a "request" to open a closed question on meta is encouraged or not because i found that a request was closed(the link in my question) Please read my question again. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I was referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801806/how-to-create-a-single-star-schema-using-ssis-for-two-different-domains), which fits your description. I will edit my answer to match your question, though.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know which part in unclear. And i thought the question was specif to the two domains i have. As for the "not shown an attempt to solve the problem" how do we show "attempts" if we the question is on a concept?.Please clarify

Comment: @Gayu If your question contains no allowance for the posting of sample code, then one solution is to post some research. Show us you've tried _something_, and we can better help you. To address the specificity of your question, I recommend picking something a little more focused, or providing a precise example. As for the clarity, I suggest rewording your question entirely so it makes a bit more sense. We understand English may not be your first language, but putting specific effort towards English usage does help.

Comment: As you can see form my post there is a comment which says "you cant expect us to go through the video.......". So i edited my question and removed those links which would show my "effort".

Comment: As for the specificity i think those who are involved in SSIS would understand the question but may be SO is not the right forum (as dystroy mentioned above)for this question since its on a concept and not on any specific issue as SO wants it to be. As for the "English may not be your first language" this is ridiculous. I am sure my English usage is good enough for any lay man to understand which i prefer rather than using bombastic words (hope you see my English usage here ;) nothing offensive)and making the question difficult to understand .

Comment: I think you do not understand SSIS concepts i addressed in my question rather than my English. Anyways i will find a proper forum which would take in my question. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

If you vote for reopen the question,
you required 4 other vote for reopen your question.

If you able to get 4 other vote with your reopen vote your question will be reopen.